# android ColorStateList created programmatically and applied to TextColor

Tags: android, textcolor, android-selector

I'm trying to apply a ColorStateList created via code as TextColor of a TextView.
The problem is that if I use a ColorStateList defined in xml it works, but do not works when I create via code the ColorStateList.

Here is how i create the ColorStateList

```
int[][] states = new int[][] { new int[] { android.R.attr.state_activated } };

int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#FFFF00") };

myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```

and I simple apply this to a TextView in this way

```
myTextView.setTextColor(myList);
```

and does not work. Using this xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:state_activated="true"  android:color="@color/yellow" />
   <item android:color="@color/black" />
</selector>
```

it works either setting the text color in the xml and by code in this way

```
myTextView.setTextColor(myTextView.getContext().getResources().getColorStateList(R.drawable.textcolor_selector));
```

I've searched for a solution all around the web, but I really can't find what's causing this problem, can anyone please help me?

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should add a default value to your state list. In your case, the opposite state of state_activated:

```
int[][] states = new int[][] { new int[] { android.R.attr.state_activated }, new int[] { -android.R.attr.state_activated } };
int[] colors = new int[] { Color.parseColor("#FFFF00"), Color.BLACK };
myList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
```